# How do I triangulate a 3d coordinate from two 2d points?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, 2d, triangulation

I'm working on a project with two infrared positioning cameras which output the (X,Y) coordinate of any IR source. I'm placing them next to each other and my goal is to measure the 3D coordinate (X,Y,Z) of the IR source, using the same technique our eyes use to measure depth.

I have drawn a (lousy) sketch here

[image]

which illustrates what I'm trying to calculate. The red dot is my IR source, which can also be seen on the 'views' of the camera to the right. I am trying to measure the length of the blue line.

I have a few known variables:

- The cameras have a resolution of 1024x768 (which also means that this is the maximum of the (X,Y) coordinate mentioned earlier)
- Horizontally the field of view is 41deg, vertically 31deg.
- I have yet to decide on the distance between cameras (AB), but this will be a known variable. Let's make it 30 cm for now.

Sadly I cannot seem to find the focal length of the camera.

Ultimately I'm hoping for an (X,Y,Z) coordinate relative to the middle point of AB. How would I go about measuring (Z)?

Comment: These lecture notes on [Depth From Stereo](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fidler/slides/2015/CSC420/lecture12_hres.pdf) explain the situation really well. Note that the computed depth is a multiple of the focal length. If you're not able to find this you can determine it by placing objects at known distances.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well aligned your cameras are, but from your pictures I am beginning to assume that the camera A and camera B are so well aligned that the rectangle representing the camera B's screen is simply horizontal translation of the rectangle representing the camera A's screen. What I mean by that is that the corresponding edges of the screens' rectangles are parallel to each other and the two rectangular screens lie in a common vertical plane perpendicular to the ground. Now, consider the plane parallel to the vertical plane that contains the two camera screens and passing through the focal points A and B of the two cameras. Call this latter plane the `screen_plane`. Also, the focal points A and B are at an equal height from the ground. If that is the case, and if I assume that `c = |AB|` is the distance between the focal points of the two cameras, and if I put a coordinate system at A, so that the x axis is horizontal to the ground, the y axis is perpendicular to the ground, and the z axis is parallel to the ground but perpendicular to the screen, then the focal point of camera B would have coordinates `( c,  0,  0 )`. As an example, you have given `c = 30 cm`. Also the `screen_plane` is spanned by the x and y axes described above and the z axis is perpendicular to the `screen_plane`.

If that is the setting you want to work with, then the red point P will appear on both screens with the same coordinate `Y_A = Y_B` but different coordinates `X_A` and `X_B`. 
Then let us denote by `theta` the horizontal field of view angle, which you have determined as `theta = 41 deg`. Just to be clear, I am assuming the angle between the leftmost side to the rightmost side of view is `2 * theta = 82 deg`.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to calculate the distance `Z` between the vertical plane `screen_plane` that contains both camera focal points and the plane parallel to `screen_plane` and passing through the red point P, i.e. you are trying to calculate the distance from P to the vertical plane `screen_plane`.

Then, here is how you calculate `Z`:

**Step 1:** From the image of point P on screen A calculate the distances (e.g. the number of pixels) from P to the vertical edges of the screen. Say they are `dist_P_to_left_edge` and `dist_P_to_right_edge`. Set

```
a_A = dist_P_to_left_edge / (dist_P_to_left_edge + dist_P_to_right_edge) (this one is not really necessary)
b_A = dist_P_to_right_edge / (dist_P_to_left_edge + dist_P_to_right_edge)
```

**Step 2:** Do the same with the image of point P on screen B:

```
a_B = dist_P_to_left_edge / (dist_P_to_left_edge + dist_P_to_right_edge)
b_B = dist_P_to_right_edge / (dist_P_to_left_edge + dist_P_to_right_edge) (this one is not really necessary)
```

**Step 3:** Apply the formula:

```
Z = c * cot(theta) / (2 * (1 - b_A - a_B) )
```

So for example, from the pictures of the screens of camera A and B you have provided, I measured with a ruler, that

```
b_A = 4/38
a_B = 12.5/38
```

and from the data you have included

```
theta = 41 deg
c = 30 cm
```

so I have calculated that the length of the blue segment on your picture is

```
Z = 30 * cos(41*pi/180) / (sin(41*pi/180) * (1 - 4/38 - 12.5/38))
  = 60.99628 cm
```